# Set Google Photos source to OneDrive storage

Tags: gallery, google

I'm subscribed to 6TB storage of OneDrive. I use this mainly to store my photos.
But as the OneDrive is not a photo-specific app, it has very less features compared to Google Photos.

So is there any way I can use Google Photos as my photos app but it will load the photos from OneDrive storage.
Or is there any other apps do the same ?

Comment: Which OS? Android?

Comment: @zomega Android